# Unit Test : VSTestHost.exe has stopped working. VS2008 Pro - Compact Framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-cf-3.5, smart-device

When trying to execute Unit Testing On a SmartDevice project on Visual Studio 2008 Pro, I get an error "VSTestHost.exe has stopped working".

When debuging the Unit Test, I have the following exception `FileNotFoundException`

and the stack trace is as follows :

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeviceConnectivity.Interop.ConManServerClass.DownloadPackage(String pwszPackageId)
at Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.FileDeployer.DownloadPackage(ObjectId packageId)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.TestHostAdapter.DeviceAgent.RunConfigDevice.InitializeStreamingWithDevice()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.TestHostAdapter.DeviceAgent.DeviceHostAdapter.initializeInternal()    
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72fbc539-cf28-4643-b7bf-2ced70018d2e/unit-test-unhandled-exception-of-type-systemiofilenotfoundexception-occurred-in?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs), it worked.

> I used filemon.exe and saw that for some reason the vstesthost.exe was looking for Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.UnitTestFramework.dll in the public assemblies folder of VS 2010  (c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies) instead of VS 2008 (c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies).
>
> Maybe not the most elegant solution, but I just copied the SmartDevice.UnitTestFramework.dll with its xml config file from the VS 2008 public assemblies folder to VS 2010 public assemblies folder and it worked for me.

Comment: Or to the latest VS public assemblies folder : copy Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.UnitTestFramework.dll to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies